# How to keep the WakeLock for as long as an application is open/running?

Tags: android

I need to keep a SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK for as long as my application is running. Before somebody lectures me on good or bad practice and how this messes with the device's own power management, this will be on a dedicated device and are the client's express wishes.

Most of the places where I see this only talk about using the WakeLock for a limited amount of time while you do something for example. I've tried to get the lock at the start of the application, but it is not working.

My questions are:
- Where should I put it so that I can keep the lock for the duration of my application?
- If the lock goes out of scope in a method does it stop working? 
- Should I be refreshing it or something ?

How would you go about achieving something like this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can provide your own implementation of Application for your app, and store your Wakelock in there.  Obtain the lock in the onCreate() method of the Application, and you'll have it for as long as your Application is running.

See the documentation for how to override it - you essentially just need to define it in your manifest file.  For example:

```
<application android.name="com.example.MyApplication" ... >
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 1):

Setting android:keepScreenOn="true" in the layout should do the same thing.

Comment: I edited the question to specify which lock I'm trying to keep. I don't want the screen on at all times, I need it to eventually dim, but keep it from turning off. Also I have lots of screens, should I add something like that to all ? Is there something like that but for the SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at userActivity(). You can call it periodicaly to reset the user activity timer(as if the user did some thing like touch the screen).

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#userActivity(long, boolean)